# AngularJS , adding 2 extra input text boxes with id and ng-model and they are not getting submitted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-form, angularjs-model

I have been modifying a form which I have done many times.  This time someone I cannot figure out WHY it is not sending 2 extra fields

Controller

```
vm.question = {};
```

Now most of the time they will be blank, but I don't recall having a problem with blank field values not being sent

Existing field that works

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-2" for="english">Spanish</label>
   <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" ng-model="vm.question.VerbiageSpanish"
             id="verbiagespanish" name="verbiagespanish"
             class="form-control"
             placeholder="Spanish" />
   </div>
</div>
```

NEW FIELDS ADDED TO FORM   `ng-model`  but are not getting submitted on saving

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-2" for="english">Parent ID</label>
     <div class="col-md-10">
       <input type="text" ng-model="vm.question.ParentId"
             numbers-only style="width:30px" id="parentid"
             name="parentid" class="form-control" />
     </div>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-2" for="english">Parent Value</label>
     <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" ng-model="vm.question.ParentValue"
            style="width:220px" id="parentvalue" name="parentvalue" 
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Parent Value" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Example of the code, notice that it HAS VerbiageSpanish and all the other fields except for the new ParentId and ParentValue 
How is this possible?

```
{
  "Active": true,
  "Name": "test",
  "Description": "test",
  "Verbiage": "test",
  "VerbiageSpanish": "test",
  "directive": {
    "1": true
  },
  "data": {
    "1": "yes"
  },
  "SortOrder": {
    "1": "2"
  }
}
```

Update based on comments:

1. If I fill out the ParentId and ParentValue,  then I see that it is sent over as I even console.log and see it
2. form submit button

   ```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal"
            ng-click="vm.saveQuestion(vm.question)">
       Save
    </button>
   ```
3. controller sends all to a service so it is clearly not even sending to the API when not having any values

   ```
   vm.saveQuestion = function (script) {
       var promise = "";
       console.log('savequestion debug', script);
   ```

when I do put in data into those textboxes I see this

```
{
  "Active": true,
  "Name": "test",
      "ParentId" : "22",
      "ParentValue": "afafaf",
  "Description": "test",
  "Verbiage": "test",
  "VerbiageSpanish": "test",
  "directive": {
    "1": true
  },
  "data": {
    "1": "yes"
  },
  "SortOrder": {
    "1": "2"
  }
}
```

Comment: you sure, you are putting these two fields in same form?

Comment: Show ur API call for posting this. I think u didn't append the above fields

Comment: @WasifKhan   -  on button submit it is only sending me the values of what is filled out  :/   that is not normal , right?   perhaps my bad way of doing forms?

Comment: @Vivz  -  what do you mean appended ,   I edited questions with more code  , thx in advance

Comment: I assume you're using ControllerAs syntax? (i.e., 'vm') If so, in the controller you'd have this.question = {}; Also - instead of passing vm.question from the template to the controller method, don't pass anything, but in the method act on this.question - what does the console.log give you then?

Comment: Well, now since I came from .net world in which I always used  html form tag ... and mvc asp.net  ... form      I'm now wondering if me relying on all my inputs and form elements to just have `ng-model`  that I'm not getting all the data without a true <form>?

Comment: If you don't fill the data , you won't get it but if you want the keys to be present you can initialise for instance vm.question = {ParentValue:"",ParentId:""};

Comment: @rrd  -  correct   controllerAs.         var vm = this;    ...

Comment: I got your question now, Try using ng-init in those two fields, like `ng-init=""`

Comment: @WasifKhan    -  seems very hacky  :( ....

Comment: @Vivz  -   well i'm thinking that some other fields could be left blank ,  so what am looking at,   initializing all my fields if no fields are required ?   nightmare...

Comment: @JohnBaxter because its the first time someone wants to get empty fields, we always shows error like this is required field. but I am surprised that empty fields should be in ur JSOn.

Comment: @rrd     1.  I removed the parameter of data in the ng-click   2.  console.log in the event  the  vm.question  and it still shows the same issue .... missing fields not filled out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think either initialize those keys as well like in your controller

```
vm.question.VerbiageSpanish = "";
vm.question.ParentId = "";
vm.question.ParentValue = "";
```

### OR

use `ng-init=""` in those fields

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.question.ParentValue"
       style="width:220px" id="parentvalue" name="parentvalue" 
       class="form-control"
       ng-init="" placeholder="Parent Value" />
```

Comment: Well,  i'm wondering if every angularjs form that I write, if I should initialize all of those based on how angularjs / ng-model  seems to "work"

Comment: I checked in my projects as well, yes in JSON it does not make key value until it gets value.

Comment: @JohnBaxter You can use the `required` attribute to notify the user of unfilled fields and inhibit the form submit function until data is entered. This provides a better user experience than server-side validation alone because the user gets instant feedback on how to correct the error. For more infomation, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Comment: See also [AngularJS form Directive API Reference -
 Examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#example).

Comment: Initialize of the values are not working,  I am surprised they are not there -  I will try the ng-init    ....   I that doesn't work i'm going to have to add before sending to api , or in node.js i'm going to have to check for the values in req.body       :/

Comment: @georgeawg  -  well some fields are just not required.   Imagine Address2 ,  well I need parent id /value to be empty most of the time as they are part of a database daisy chain design for the eventually looping over questions and then looking up if a question has a parent or children ...   Thx for your links and advise